# Automation of ore -> ingots using Applied Energistics and Thermal Expansion in FTB Monster 1.1.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

This is my first question asked so please take it easy on me if I omit something!

I know someone will have asked this question of google previously but I can't find an answer for the life of me.

My goal is to automate the ore to ingot process from my ME network using Thermal Expansion machines. I want a bunch of specified ores to be automatically turned into ingots upon entry into the ME network with a caveat that one stack (64 ore) should always remain in the ME network. This is so that I can do whatever I please, on demand, with the ore for whatever purpose arises.

I have created the system of my choice as shown in the screenshots but I cannot work out how to create an instruction to always leave 64 of the ore in the ME network. I believe that ME Level Emitters can be used to control how many items are sent to a machine, but I kind of want the opposite: I want all items sent to the machine (in my case, an Induction Smelter) to be turned into ingots with 64 ore always left behind in the ME network.

[image: Setup 1]

[image: Setup 2]

[image: Induction Smelter configuration]

To explain the system (screenshots) I have tested in creative so far:

1x precision export bus continually filling one of the Induction Smelter input slots with sand.

2x hoppers connected to 2x precision export buses to input defined ores into the Induction Smelter. I have used two export buses as it is only possible to specify eight ores per bus and I will probably be specifying more than this to be autosmelted into ingots.

1x basic import bus which transfers the output and secondary output back into the ME network when the process is complete.

This is currently working exactly the way I want it to except not being able to control 64 ore blocks being left in the ME network unsmelted.

Is there a way I can achieve this using purely Applied Energistics and Thermal Expansion items?

I am using FTB Monster v1.1.1 MC v1.6.4

Many thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: this CAN be done, but I can't remember for the life of me how. I'll get back to you if someone else doesn't do it sooner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the export bus export only one item at a time when there is a redstone signal. Then put a level emitter on emit above level and set it to 64. Though this will need a export bus for each type of item.

Comment: Hi ModDL, thanks for your response. Yes, I had a little tinker with a level emitter controlling an export bus but couldn't get it to work. I would have persevered to get it to work as I expected it would but quickly realised that I would need an emitter for each ore which would be too vast (space wise) for my situation.

Comment: This was that 'better solution' I was talking about but couldn't remember how to do.

Comment: Thanks both for your contribution. I will accept this as the best answer as, although not right for my situation due to not having to not having the space to implement this in my SMP world, it is a solution. I should have stated in my original post that I had already identified this method as a solution but thought that there may be an alternative method that does not involve an array of level emitters controlling each particular ore.

Comment: @GamingLexus ask another question with your more specific issue due to space limitations

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways of accomplishing this I'm sure, but one way is to;

- plop a chest somewhere, and fill all the slots in its inventory except one with 1 of something, cobblestone perhaps.
- Then attach the chest to your ME network with a storage bus set for the lowest priority
- Then attach an export bus to your chest with the bus configured for whichever ore you want to keep. (this means you will need 1 chest configured this way per ore you want to save, or you can put all your ores in the chest 1 stack of ore per inventory slot, and assuming you never pull all 64 out of the chest it should work as well)
- The export bus you already have pumping stuff into your smelter will pull it out of your ME drives, but NOT this chest(s) we just set up, and you'll still be able to access this chest from any of your ME terminals.

Comment: Hi Ender,

Thanks for your prompt response. I have been playing with your suggestion for the last couple of hours and although in theory it should work, it doesn't in practice; unless I'm doing something drastically wrong!

I have filled up the chest, set storage bus to priority 0 on it where the ME Drive is set to 1. I have set export buses to the chest exporting the items (contained within the chest) to the chest. In theory, this should always keep the chest full of the items specified in the precision export buses. 

Unfortunately, the ME system still pulls from the chest into smelter.

Comment: Screenshots of setup in my test world to follow....
http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c318/gaming_lexus/2015-02-27_11.15.39_zpsgpfm4cnp.png
http://i30.photobucket.com/albums/c318/gaming_lexus/2015-02-27_11.16.05_zpsoh11zzrb.png

Comment: I have not forgotten about you, I've been having trouble with my copy of minecraft and have been troubleshooting that.

Comment: No worries - thanks for your contribution. I really liked the principle of your suggestion but just could not get it to work :(